# Why does this use of the Hash#each method work only when I remove the splat operator from the parameter?

Tags: ruby, hash, inject, splat

I'm going through a problem on Ruby Monk, https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/155-restaurant#solution4804

Their solution is great; I like it and it's more compact than mine.  Problem is for mine, I just don't understand why it only works when I remove the splat operator from the cost parameter `orders`.  Even if I shouldn't be doing it this way, I'm struggling to figure out what's up.  I know sometimes it's unnecessary to understand everything, and it's best to just move on.. but curious.

Here is mine:

```
class Restaurant
  def initialize(menu)
    @menu = menu
  end

  def cost(*orders)
    total_cost = 0
    orders.each do |item, number|
    total_cost += @menu[item] * number
  end
end

menu = {:rice => 3, :noodles => 2}
orders = {:rice => 1, :noodles => 1}
eat = Restaurant.new(menu)
puts eat.cost(orders)
```

Edit:
To include their suggested solution below

```
class Restaurant
  def initialize(menu)
    @menu = menu
  end

  def cost(*orders)
    orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
      total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
    end
  end
end
```

Edit:
To clear up and answer my own question in the comment

I tried these experiments and it shows `inject` "removing" the array brackets that splat "put on".  Perhaps not the most proper way to think about it?  It does help clear up my confusion.

```
order = { :rice => 1, :noodles => 1 }
menu = { :rice => 3, :noodles => 2 }

[order].inject(0) do |bla, blu|
    p bla       #=> 0
    p blu       #=> {:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}
    p blu.keys  #=> [:rice, :noodles]
end
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject): it iterates over the items in the collection, one at a time. As such, at each iteration you don't have an array, you only have the item from the array. It "removes" the array in the same way that `each` does, by processing the contents one element at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
def cost(*orders)
end
```

then all the parameters passed to the `cost` method will be put into a single array named `orders`. These two are thus equivalent:

```
def cost(*orders)
  p orders.class #=> Array
  p orders       #=> [1,2,3]
end
cost(1,2,3)

def cost(orders)
  p orders.class #=> Array
  p orders       #=> [1,2,3]
end
cost( [1,2,3] )     # note the array literal brackets
```

In your case, when you remove the "splat" you are saying *"set `orders` to reference whatever was passed in directly"*. In this case you're passing it a Hash, and when you iterate a hash you get key/value pairs for each entry. This is just what you want.

When you do have the splat, though, you're getting this:

```
def cost(*orders)
  p orders.class #=> Array
  p orders       #=> [{:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}]
end
orders = {:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}
cost(orders)
```

So you're wrapping your hash in an array, and then iterating over the elements of the array. Thus, the first value passed to the block is the entire hash, and there is no second parameter.

```
def cost(*orders)
  p orders.class #=> Array
  p orders       #=> [{:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}]
  orders.each do |item,number|
    p item       #=> {:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}
    p number     #=> nil
  end
end
orders = {:rice=>1, :noodles=>1}
cost(orders)
```

At this point you can't multiply anything by `nil` and so your code breaks.

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot.  Regarding the rubymonk suggested answer, does using `inject` remove the encompassing array?  I mean, why does calling what appears to be: `p [{:rice => 1, :noodles => 1}].keys  #=> rice \n noodles`